# Combining Arrays in Scala

Tags: scala

If I have `DerivedType1:BaseType` and `DerivedType2:BaseType` and `Array[DerivedType1]` and `Array[DerivedType2]`, what's the most succinct way of combining them into `Array[BaseType]`?

Comment: C++ background? Don't use `X:Y` to denote inheritance, because that's the syntax for _context bound_.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the `++` method on `Array`.

```
scala> class A; class B extends A; class C extends A
defined class A
defined class B
defined class C

scala> Array(new B, new B) ++ Array(new C, new C)
res33: Array[A] = Array(B@b7501b, B@ec5359, C@1540d0c, C@124a927)
```